# Export command line output to a file in Python

Tags: python

Here's my code to execute a jar file in Python:

```
import os
os.system("java -jar xyz.jar")
```

I can see the output on terminal, but want to store it in a file. How can I do that?

Comment: Redirect the output to a file in the terminal, using `>` ?

Comment: I want to do hundreds of iterations, so want the process to be automated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) you can pipe outputs (stdout, stderr or both) directly into file:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("java -jar xyz.jar", shell=True, stdout=open('outfile.txt', 'wt'), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Note that I added `shell=True` parameter, which is required if  your application requires shell-specific variables (such as where Java is located).

Also note that in the above call, the output streams are handled as follows:

- stderr stream is piped to stdout, and
- stdout is piped to outfile

More details on stream configurations are available in [subprocess manual page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE).

Comment: I tried, but output file is empty. But I can still see output on terminal. Where I might be doing wrong?

Comment: No, I'm just doing this.

Comment: Wait... I get it now. Your application is probably printing to stderr so you need to pipe stderr stream to the file too.

Comment: Check out the edited answer, which takes stderr into account.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonScript.py", line 15, in <module>
    subprocess.call("java -jar xyz.jar", stdout=outfile, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 533, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 848, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1446, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'java -jar xyz.jar'

Comment: Well.. You asked how to run command `java -jar xyz.jar` and store console output and the code above does just that. You surely know better than anyone else what is the actual command you want to run, if its not that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54886/discussion-between-tanay-soni-and-jsalonen).

Comment: Also, you may need to use absolute paths for programs. Using `shell=True` argument could possibly help too.

Comment: Update after a chat: In this case `shell=True` was actually required to correctly locate Java.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `os.system`, use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) instead.

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(["java", "-jar", "xyz.jar"])

file = open('file.txt', 'w+')
file.write(output)
file.close()
```

Comment: I get this error: 
File "pythonScript.py", line 4, in <module>
    output = subprocess.check_output("java -jar xyz.jar")

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonScript.py", line 2, in <module>
    output = subprocess.check_output("java -jar xyz.jar")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 603, in check_output
    with Popen(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 848, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1446, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'java -jar xyz.jar'